# Camera photo not added to file input on ios devices

Tags: javascript, iphone, file-upload, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have made a file upload area component in Blazor wasm.
Here is the view

```
<div @ref="@this.UploadContainer" class="uploadContainer text-black-50" tabindex="0">
<Icon Name="IconName.Paperclip" />
<Paragraph>
    @this.Localizer["DragAndDropFiles"]
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph>
    @string.Join(" | ", this.Files.Select(file => file.Name))
</Paragraph>
<InputFile @ref="@this.InputFile"
           OnChange="this.OnChange"
           style="display: none;" multiple />
</div>
```

Where I am using Blazorise components.
The code behind for the view

```
public partial class FileUploadArea
    : IAsyncDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; } = null!;

    [Inject]
    public IStringLocalizer<App> Localizer { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter]
    public List<IBrowserFile> Files { get; set; } = new List<IBrowserFile>();

    [Parameter]
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }

    private ElementReference UploadContainer { get; set; }

    private InputFile? InputFile { get; set; } = null!;

    private IJSObjectReference? JsModule { get; set; }

    private IJSObjectReference? FileUploadModule { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            this.JsModule = await this.JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", new object[] { "./js/fileUploadArea.js" });

            this.FileUploadModule = await this.JsModule.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("initializeFileDropZone", this.UploadContainer, this.InputFile!.Element);
        }

        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private void OnChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Disabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.Files.Clear();

        this.Files.AddRange(e.GetMultipleFiles(10));

        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (this.FileUploadModule is not null)
        {
            await this.FileUploadModule.InvokeVoidAsync("dispose");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the css for the view (in case it is relevant...)

.uploadContainer {
border-style: dotted;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: lightgrey;
text-align: center;
padding: 3em;
border-radius: 1em;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
.uploadContainer.hover {
border-style: solid;
}

And here is the javascript code that is supposed to make it work

```
export function initializeFileDropZone(dropZoneElement, inputFile) {

function onClick(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let input = document.createElement('input');

    input.type = inputFile.type;

    input.accept = inputFile.accept

    input.multiple = inputFile.multiple;

    input.onchange = e => {

        inputFile.files = e.target.files;

        const event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });

        inputFile.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    input.click();
}

function onDragHover(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    dropZoneElement.classList.add("hover");
}

function onDragLeave(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    dropZoneElement.classList.remove("hover");
}


function onDrop(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    dropZoneElement.classList.remove("hover");

    inputFile.files = e.dataTransfer.files;

    const event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });

    inputFile.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function onPaste(e) {

    inputFile.files = e.clipboardData.files;

    const event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });

    inputFile.dispatchEvent(event);
}

// Register all events
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("click", onClick);
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragenter", onDragHover);
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragover", onDragHover);
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragleave", onDragLeave);
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("drop", onDrop);
dropZoneElement.addEventListener('paste', onPaste);

// The returned object allows to unregister the events when the Blazor component is destroyed
return {
    dispose: () => {
        dropZoneElement.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
        dropZoneElement.removeEventListener('dragenter', onDragHover);
        dropZoneElement.removeEventListener('dragover', onDragHover);
        dropZoneElement.removeEventListener('dragleave', onDragLeave);
        dropZoneElement.removeEventListener("drop", onDrop);
        dropZoneElement.removeEventListener('paste', onPaste);
    }
}
}
```

The input on the page is hidden, so that on the upload area is visible. Clicks on the upload area are handled by the javascript which creates a new file input with the same parameters as the hidden one and open it, then transfer the files to the hidden file input so the onchange even from the code behind is triggered.

This works fine on PC and Android devices, but on iPhone and iPad, the camera opens, but any photos taken are not passed to the onChange of the hidden input.
How can I make this work consistently with the camera across all devices.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Apple non-compliance.  Generally speaking, when media actions fail on mobile devices, it's because you haven't caught a user interaction at a time that particular browser considers sufficient.  Either that, or it wants you to have permissions that your action hasn't established-- in this case, the right to use the device's camera logic.  Try `accept="image/*"` in the file input control, or try to get  permissions explicitly.  (Sorry I don't have any Apple products, so I cannot test any particular attempts to help you, just speaking from general experience).

Comment: Thanks @Bennyboy1973, I'll give that a try. I thought I tried that one already and that it restricted the file type to images only (whereas I want any file type) though.

Comment: Well, it definitely won't offer open file access if you you accept only images, so my comment won't help you much.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found a solution. By wrapping the `UploadContainer` div in a label for the file input element, it is possible to dispense with the js click handler.
The label redirects the click to the file input element and the js code which redirected the click event and was apparently causing the problem is gone.

The view new looks like this

```
<Label For="@fileUploadId"
   Style="width: 100%;">
<div @ref="@this.UploadContainer" class="uploadContainer text-black-50" tabindex="0">
    <Icon Name="IconName.Paperclip" />
    <Paragraph>
        @this.Localizer["DragAndDropFiles"]
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
        @string.Join(" | ", this.Files.Select(file => file.Name))
    </Paragraph>
    <InputFile id="@fileUploadId"
               @ref="@this.InputFile"
               OnChange="this.OnChange"
               style="display: none;"
               multiple />
</div>
</Label>
```

where `@fileUploadId` is a static string in the code behind.

It seems to work fine on desktop with Chrome, iPad with Chrome and Safari and iPhone with Safari.